# How to check for inline function hooking in Windows?

Tags: windows, c++

Can anyone tell me how to check for inline function hooking? I installed the famous root-kit Hacker Defender. It uses inline function hooking technique. But when I check 5 first bytes of the function in Windows API, I can't see op-code for jump instruction. How can I detect whether or not a function is hooked? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Rootkit Unhooker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/Rootkit-Unhooker.shtml) can detect inline hooking.
[image]

[GMER](http://www.gmer.net) also does that according to its specifications.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to write a C++ program to detect it without using available tools. Do you know how?

Comment: @Thang reverse engineering the program or look for source code..

Comment: If I know the reasons, perhaps I don't waste your time and my time here, also the sites like this are useless.